Are license plate flippers legal on public roads if you flip between identical license plates?
Assuming the car is legally registered, and you have two of the same license plates, would it be legal to have a license plate flipper that flips between the two identical license plates and drive this on a public road?
I'm aware that some states have banned license plate flippers specifically, but some states (Georgia for example) only require the license plate to not sway and be visible and unobstructed at all times (https://law.stackexchange.com/a/19228/76031). So would this theoretically be public street legal?
This question was inspired by this YT short: https://youtube.com/shorts/LGIsQAfsyWw?si=OrBh-V0eY_QLrhba

Unless they are to go on the front AND rear, why would the state have issued 2 of the same plate?

And, on the flipped side, it is missing the Month/Year registration sticker. "06-24". So that is "Not Valid"

Surely there must be a way to get additional license plates with Month/Year registration stickers on both somehow, or maybe use both license plates in the back in a state where the front license plate is optional @WPNSGuy

"Additional license plates" - You would be asked, "What happened to the originals?" Are you going to lie about it? And if the state only requires the rear, they will only issue one.

What about getting the license plates in one state and putting them on a car in a different state, is that possible? @WPNSGuy

That is illegal. That plate + car combination does not exist in either states DMV database.

@WPNSGuy, Washington State used to replace the physical license plates every seven years (due to wear and tear on the reflective coating), and you had the option to get new plates with the same numbers as the old plates.  So yes, there are circumstances under which you can legally have two copies of a set of plates.

@WPNSGuy I would like to update my question slightly, because I notice that you're focused on answering just my specific proposed suggestion to how to make this arguably legal. I'm really looking for any case where it may legally be allowed to do this. Are there no circumstances under which you can have two identical plates that both look identical in the rear of your car? Another suggestion would be driving a european car in a one-plate state.

Are you asking about the legal situation in a state that has expressly banned flippers?

@EricB - In your linked video, the flipped one is already "illegal". It lacks the Month/Year sticker. I cannot envision a circumstance where you'd have more than the required number of identical, valid, state issued plates, at the same time.

The answer would depend on how the law is written.  If the law requires some fraudulent intent or actual misrepresentation, the answer will be "no."  If the law bans the devices outright then the answer will either be "yes" or something more complicated.

There is no answer common to the entire United States.
The legality depends entirely on the wording of the statute, and each jurisdiction may enact such a restriction differently.
For example, one could ban them outright using language such as:

"The use, possession, installation, manufacturing or sales of any device capable of..."

Alternately, another jurisdiction could choose to focus only on curtailing the specific act these devices are intended to enable by stating:

"It is illegal to use any device to switch the license plate to display a different number while driving."

In the first example it would be illegal, while in the second it would be legal.  You would have to research the law in any state you plan to drive if you owned such a device.
P.S. The likelihood of having legally issued identical plates is irrelevant to a legal analysis of the hypothetical question being asked.

No
new-south-wales
You are only allowed to display the government issued plates and you only get two - one for the front and one for the back.
Getting a replacement requires you to return the damaged plate or to swear or affirm a statutory declaration that the plate has been lost or stolen. If you do the former, you still only have two plates, if you lie on a stat dec, you’ve broken the law.

What if you buy and register a car in say a European country where both license plates are identical and legal, and then travel to a one-plate state and move the front license plate to the back?

What about personalised plates? Could you order three copies of the plate?

This isn't really a direct answer to my question since the question presumes that you have two identical license plates in a one-plate state. Is this presumption wrong? Is there truly no way of getting two identical plates legally on a car and then driving it in a one-plate state?

@EricB Australia doesn’t have any one plate states

@EricB Front abd back plates in the EU are not fully identical - one has the Technical inspection mark, the other not! And you are forced to have a front and back plate.

@nick012000 - I have personalized plates (Virginia). No, you cannot order extras. You get one set...one plate for the front and one plate for the back.

@Trish you say "EU" when you mean "Germany."  Many EU countries have identical front and rear plates and have no "technical inspection mark" on the plate.  At least one EU country, furthermore, does not manufacture plates itself but requires vehicle registrants to provide them subject to certain standards.

@EricB Don't you need to follow the laws based on where you car is registered? If you register in a local that only has a single plate you won't get into issues when traveling to a locale that requires front and back plates.
